# Creating a code for Moving onto Next Row upon Clicking on Button

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro where upon clicking on Button1, the selection(DateofRequest) would move to cell C6 and PayeesName on Cell D6; another click when the name is entered move to C7 and D7 respectively and so on and so forth until all the cells are filled.

I will appreciate any help on this. Thank you!

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim DateofRequest As Date
    Dim PayeesName As String

    Worksheets("C Check Request").Select
    DateofRequest = Range("C13")
    Worksheets("C Check Request").Select
    PayeesName = Range("C15")

    Worksheets("Costume").Select
    Worksheets("Costume").Range("C5").Select
    RowCount = Worksheets("Costume").Range("C5").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    With Worksheets("Costume")
        RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(RowCount, 3) = DateofRequest
        .Cells(RowCount, 4) = PayeesName 
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: Agree with Scott, this needs to be a lot more clear.  I would add "Excel Macro" to the title and present a specific question / problem.

Comment: So I have an excel spreadsheets titled Costume and a form that i am using to populate the information named "C Check Request". So what i am trying to accomplish is that, whenever the Payee's name is entered in the form, it should appear on the spreadsheet titled Costume. I can get the first name entered appear on the sheet but when the second name is entered, it delete the previous name instead of moving to the next row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to increase the count in columns C and D but are looking for the last row in A.

Also your code can be shortened by getting rid of the selects and activates.  Also you can assign the values directly instead of using variables.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim RowCount as Long
    With Worksheets("Costume")
        RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(RowCount, 3) = Worksheets("C Check Request").Range("C13").Value
        .Cells(RowCount, 4) = Worksheets("C Check Request").Range("C15").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, but this is behaving exactly as my code. any suggestion reading thru my comment on your first post?

Comment: @collinsosei did you replace all your cod with mine.  It shouldn't.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thank you so very much. It works like a charm! I really appreciate your help.